How to cast from type as generic parameter into trait as generic parameter (also show limitation)
I want a list that:

contains some value that implements a trait which is generic parameter,
allows to push a value of type T and returns IdOf<T>,
and get the value with IdOf<T>,

The code is expected to be:
pub struct TypedList<TBase: ?Sized> {
    values: Vec<Box<TBase>>,
}

pub struct IdOf<T: ?Sized> {
    id: usize,
    p: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> IdOf<T> {
    pub fn new(id: usize) -> Self {
        IdOf { id, p: PhantomData }
    }

    pub fn id(&self) -> usize {
        self.id
    }
}

impl<TBase: ?Sized> TypedList<TBase> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        TypedList { values: Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn push<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized>(&'a mut self, elem: Box<T>) -> IdOf<T>
    where
        T: TBase, // err
    {
        let id = self.values.len();
        let cast_elem: Box<TBase> = elem; // err
        self.values.push(cast_elem);
        return IdOf::<T>::new(id);
    }

    pub fn get<'a, T>(&'a mut self, id: IdOf<T>) -> &'a mut T
    where
        T: TBase, // err
    {
        return self.values[id.id()].downcast(); // how to
    }
}

How can I do so?
Note:

TypedList needs to own the values.
TypedList needs to be able to enumerate values as TBase.

In requirement, 1 TypedList contains factories and be used to generate another TypedList.
One facatory's create() may want objects in the second TypedList, with it's original type.

I don't think you can do this generically without CoerceUnsized which is not yet stabilized. Is a nightly-only solution appropriate?

I can solve it by using macro to generate type definitions, but It is odd and I need to name it once using. (While I heard that rust itself generate code for each generic)

It looks like you are trying to think OOP in Rust. Don't.

Looking at your code, I will try to explain how the compiler sees it.
You have declared a TypedList struct that contains the vector. All elements of this vec have the same type! However, when you call a push method you want to push any type unrelated to the original one.
There are two ways out.

Store not a specific type but Box<dyn Trait>. And in the push method indicate that T: Trait
Specify that one type can be converted to another: T: Into<TBase>



I need trait as a generic type parameter, but currently rust don't support T:TBase. 2. T: Into<TBase> requires TBase to be Sized, which can't be a trait

